# Heritrix DecidingScope regexp URI

Tags: regex, heritrix

I'm using HERITRIX to crawl a site called octetfarm.com.   I would like the crawler to do a regexp on the URI (or URL) and if the string "octetfarm" is present, the crawler should accept it.

I made 2 rules

## 1 MatchesRegExpDecideRule "ACCEPT" and regexp "*.octetfarm.*"

## 2 rejectByDefault

When I launch the crawler on octetfarm.com (my very simple test site) the first page is just a link as below:

```
<a href="http://octetfarm.com/layer1/layer1.html">layer1</a>
```

Why does the crawler not follow that simple link which includes the string "octetfarm".

here are my rules in xml

```
 <newObject name="decide-rules" class="org.archive.crawler.deciderules.DecideRuleSequence">
    <map name="rules">
      <newObject name="rejectByDefault" class="org.archive.crawler.deciderules.RejectDecideRule">
      </newObject>
      <newObject name="octetfarm" class="org.archive.crawler.deciderules.MatchesRegExpDecideRule">
        <string name="decision">ACCEPT</string>
        <string name="regexp">*.octetfarm.*</string>
      </newObject>
    </map>
  </newObject>
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex you have listed there isn't quite right; try this instead:

```
<string name="regexp">.*octetfarm.*</string>
```

The only difference between this and yours is the two characters directly preceeding `octetfarm` having been reversed.

`.*` in a regex is a statement with two parts. `.` tells the regex to match any character (typically by default excludes newline characters), and `*` tells the regex to match 0 or more of whatever directly precedes it.

The effect of this regex in full is then to match if there are 0 or more of any characters until the string `octetfarm` is seen, followed by 0 or more of any characters.

Wrapping the string `octetfarm` with `.*` either side is actually only important if the regex engine is trying to match the full string; you may find that just the regex as follows may work for you, as depending on the settings of the regex engine it may just look for any instance in the supplied text where it finds a match:

```
<string name="regexp">octetfarm</string>
```